# Why my ionicApp takes version of Android browser 4.0

Tags: android, ionic-framework, webrtc, crosswalk

I have created an Ionic Angular Project and added cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview, since I need to integrate Webrtc.

But still, when build the android app and run in android device of version 7.1, I get error, android browser 4.0 doesnt support this.

How to make my app to use crosswalk webview instead of android?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a entirely new ionic project, added the cordova plugin, before adding platform to it.

Then I build the apk, it worked with crosswalk in android.